# How to maintain session in asp.net?

Tags: c#

I am checking session on page load event. when i am close browser. session is abandon how can i prevent when i close browser.

```
if (Session["UserID"] != null)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Securepage/AboutMe.aspx", false);
}
```

Comment: what are u trying to ask .?

Comment: @mmhasannn if browser is close than session is clear? or not

Comment: Yes if browser is closed than Session values are lost.

Comment: Any one can tell me how maintain session?

Comment: @mmhasann, so please tell me how to maintain session after closed browser.

Comment: You should read: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, session will be lost if you close the browser. If you want to maintain the session, try looking at cookies.

You can refer here. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)